# Recursion not exiting on the base case in merge sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am learning python and was implementing 2D matrix merge sort and my code goes to infinite loop while calling merge sort and i am unable to find the reason for the same.

```
def mergesort(arr,l,r,u,d):
    if(l>=r or u>=d):
        return

    else :
        mid_h = l + int((r-1)/2)
        mid_v = u + int((d-1)/2)

        print( l,mid_h)
        print(u,mid_v)

        mergesort(arr,l,mid_h,u,mid_v)
        mergesort(arr,mid_h+1,r,u,mid_v)
        mergesort(arr,l,mid_h,mid_v+1,d)
        mergesort(arr,mid_h+1,r,mid_v+1,d)

        merge_row(arr,l,mid_h,r,u,mid_v,d)
        merge_col(arr,l,mid_h,r,u,mid_v,d)
```

Comment: l , r, u,d represent left , right ,up and down respectively

Comment: Can you provide a *small* example value for `arr` that triggers infinite recursion? Do  `merge_row` or `merge_col` call `mergesort` at all?

Comment: Put `print(l, r, u, d)` at the beginning, so you see if you're always getting closer to the base case.

Comment: I don't get the logic behind the code though. You are sorting by what exactly?

Comment: `x + y/2` is only the midpoint between `x` and `y` if `x == 0`. You want something like `x + (x - y)/2`.

Comment: merge_row and merge_col don't call mergesort.

Comment: arr=
18 4 16 8        23 13 20 11.         28 24 26 25.        1 30 15 19. with l=0 r=3 u=0 d=3. it reaches the infinite loop at l=2 and r=3  and u=2 d=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your midpoints aren't actually midpoints. Consider `l == 5` and `r == 8`. Then `l + r//2 == 5 + 4 == 9`.

Instead, you want

```
# Add half the distance between the endpoints, not half the far endpoint.
mid_h = l + (r - l) // 2
mid_v = u + (d - u) // 2
```